# Putty fails to connect to Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to connect to the Vagrant server using putty with IP:127.0.0.1 and port:2222. Yesterday i login successfully using username:vagrant and pass:vagrant. Today, unforunately this is what i received is a dialog box:"PuTTy fatal error:network error:Connection refused". Any ideas/suggestions about how to fix that

Comment: Is your vagrant server running?

Comment: i typed "vagrant up" and "vagrant init". An error"Could not open the files user/myname/base. So i guess there something wrong with that.

Comment: Are you in the folder that contains your Vagrantfile?

Comment: i already installed the virtual box and vagrant package. I typed those words above "vagrant up" and"vagrant inti" in cmd

Comment: No, i am not. I guess that's the problem

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try configuring a static IP address for your VM in your Vagrantfile. Through past experience, I've found this to be a more stable way of connecting to your VM via SSH/SCP/SFTP or similar.

To set a static IP address (e.g. in this case 192.168.50.10), you'd put the following in your VagrantFile:

```
# Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the VM
# using the Static IP 192.168.50.10
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.50.10"
```

This is documented in more detail in the Vagrant Documentation on [Private Networks](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html).

Once you've configured a static IP (and rerun 'vagrant up' or 'vagrant reload'), you should be able to connect to your VM using Putty/SSH by using that Static IP (192.168.50.10) and port 22.